# Include custom classes in Kohana 3 user guide

Tags: kohana-3

I am trying to figure out how to [enable the Kohana 3 User Guide](http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=how_to_use_kodocs_to_include_your_custom_files_in_the_kohana_user_guide_api_browser) in my application and to automatically include my custom code in the API guide that is built.

Comment: Cool, but maybe you should post the link as an answer so people don't think this question needs answering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is correct, but this works for me: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Kohana#find_file

Answer (score -1):

Bart Gottschalk has posted the steps on the Unofficial Kohana 3.0 Wiki which you can find by following [this link](http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=how_to_use_kodocs_to_include_your_custom_files_in_the_kohana_user_guide_api_browser).

I just got tired of running into this question in the unanswered section.